# VBA scripting.dictionary check if dictionary contents dates or numeric or alpha numeric?

Tags: vba, dictionary, key, numeric, alphanumeric

I am just creating list of unique items using dictionary from different columns and feeding them into a combo boxes. I would like to know if there a way to check if the dictionary contains only numeric values or alphanumeric because some columns contains only numbers and other contains text and dates.

```
With Sheets("Database")
cNr = WorksheetFunction.Match(fString, .Rows(1), 0)

lRo = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        For Each c In Range(.Cells(2, cNr), .Cells(lRo, cNr))
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                If Not d.Exists(c.Value) Then d.Add c.Value, 1
            End If
        Next c
    k = d.keys
End With
```

I have one more question. I would like to loop this and create unique list of each columns and store it in k1 , k2, k3 ...and so on. how do i do this?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'''your code
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In d
    If Not IsNumeric(key) Then
        MsgBox "dictionary has a text value!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next key
'''your code
```

**updated against OP requirements**

```
Sub test()
    Dim key As Variant, d As Object: Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    Dim c As Range, i As Range: Set i = Range([A2], Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "C"))
    For Each c In i
        If c.Column = 1 Then
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                If Not d.Exists(c.Value) Then d.Add c.Value, c.Column
            End If
        Else
            If Not IsNumeric(c.Value2) Then
                If Not d.Exists(c.Value & " text") Then d.Add c.Value & " text", c.Column
            Else
                If Not d.Exists(c.Value) Then d.Add c.Value, c.Column
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    Debug.Print "field", "value"
    For Each key In d
        Debug.Print d(key), key
    Next key
End Sub
```

*test*

[image]

Comment: thanks .i will try.  I have one more question. I would like to loop this and create unique list of each columns and store it in k1 , k2, k3 ...and so on. how do i do this?

Comment: could you please provide your data sample (fake), I will show you the way

Comment: ok thanks for your answers but i don't understand now how i get the unique values of each column to populate my combo boxes?.

Comment: @Shan post has been updated, now dictionary has only unique values of each column, not numeric values has marked as " text".

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub setColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, c As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long
    Dim dCols As Object, dCol As Object, cType As String, cel As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set dCols = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ws
        With .UsedRange
            lr = .Row + .Rows.Count - 1
            lc = .Column + .Columns.Count - 1
        End With
        For c = .UsedRange.Column To lc
            Set dCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            For r = .UsedRange.Row + 1 To lr
                If r = .UsedRange.Row + 1 Then
                    Select Case True
                        Case IsNumeric(.Cells(2, c)):   cType = "Number"
                        Case IsDate(.Cells(2, c)):      cType = "Date"
                        Case Else:                      cType = "Text"
                    End Select
                End If
                If Len(.Cells(r, c).Value) > 0 Then dCol(r) = .Cells(r, c).Value
            Next
            If dCol.Count > 1 Then
                dCols(c & "type") = cType
                Set dCols(c) = dCol
            End If: Set dCol = Nothing
        Next
        For c = .UsedRange.Column To lc
            .Cells(lr + c + 1, 1) = "Row" & c & ", Col" & c & " Type: " & dCols(c & "type")
            .Cells(lr + c + 1, 2).Value = "Value: " & dCols(c)(c + 1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

[image]